# Cannot read integers from a txt file containing 2 columns (C++)

Tags: c++, text-files

i have to write a code that prompts user to enter a file name (containing 2 columns of integer). The program then reads that file, prints out the numbers set.

My txt file looks like this (the numbers are separated by space):

2 3

5 6

7 8

8 9

5 7

I thought it would be easy, but now i stuck. When i run the program, this line appeared

"There're no number in the file."

I set number to "int", so why can't the compiler read the number? But when i change the type to "string", the numbers did appear O_O , since i later need to calculate the average of those num also, i cannot use string.

Here is my code, I appreciate any help TT___TT

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream in_file;
    string filename;
    int number;
    int number1;
    cout << "In order to process, please enter the file name: ";
    cin >> filename;
    in_file.open(filename.c_str());
    if (!in_file.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Cannot open file" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        in_file >> number;
        if (in_file.fail())
        {
            cout << "There're no number in the file." << endl;
        }
        while (in_file >> number >> number1)
        {
            cout  << number << " " << number1;
        }
    }

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're wrong with the sequential logic, rather use a loop like `while (in_file >> number >> number1)`

Comment: sorry, that's because i typed it wrong

Comment: but it's still not working

Comment: As mentioned you got the sequential logic wrong. Before entering the loop you already read `number` once.

Answer (score 1):

Error in your logic:

```
    in_file >> number;   // Assigns 2 from first line to number
    if (in_file.fail())
    {
        cout << "There're no number in the file." << endl;
    }

    while (in_file >> number >> number1) // Assigns 3 to number from first line
                                         // and assigns 5 to number1 from second line
    {
        cout  << number << " " << number1;
    }
```

You need to use just:

```
    while (in_file >> number >> number1)
    {
        cout  << number << " " << number1;
    }
```

If you must print "There're no number in the file." in the output, you can use:

```
    bool gotSomeNumbers = false;
    while (in_file >> number >> number1)
    {
        cout  << number << " " << number1;
        gotSomeNumbers = true;
    }

    if (!gotSomeNumbers)
    {
         cout << "There're no number in the file." << endl;
    }
```

Comment: Well, that doesn't print `cout << "There're no number in the file." << endl;`.

Comment: I tried deleting that part just as what you said but it doesn't work :(( Thank you!

Comment: @ZukuYuka, what does "it doesn't work mean"? Not compiling, not producing the right output, what output is it producing?

Comment: "Press any key to continue." This line appeared ;;A ;;

Comment: @ZukuYuka, did you see any other message?

Comment: @RSahu nope :( Jonathan: yea I'm sure

Comment: @RSahu the strange thing is when i change number and number1 to string type, it works :|

Comment: @ZukuYuka, that surprises me.

Answer (score 0):

> The method you are using to find to know whether file is empty is not
>   correct in following way :: As soon as this line gets executed
>
> ```
> in_file >> number;
> ```
>
> The compiler will treat first line as an integer as a whole , i.e.
>   number = "2  3" in given scenario. now this is not a standard number
>   because of space in between 2 and 3 and
>
> ### `in_file.fail()` will return true.
>
> The Correct way is to use "eof" function as follows : (I also added
>   1-2 lines to calculate average of these numbers as you mentioned)

[Correct code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yG8Ct.jpg)

> Reference :  
>       [When will ofstream::open fail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835848/when-will-ofstreamopen-fail)
>       [Checking for an empty file in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390912/checking-for-an-empty-file-in-c)

Comment: The code breaks due to "Integer division by zero." /____\

Comment: just put everything after **if** scope in **else** scope... : 
**else** **{** **int** **sum** **=0**......upto **cout<<sum/count**...............}
and you are good to go